# Question about Debye's and Einstein's Heat Capacity Theory

Tags: waves, solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons, density-of-states

I am reading the phonon part of Omar's textbook, but
I am a bit confused over the way through which the distribution of the frequencies of oscillators are determined. In Einstein's model all oscillators are assumed to vibrate at the same frequency. However, from (3. 33) it seems that in Debye's model it is assumed that each vibration mode only appears once. Is it generally true? Why is that?
(Or instead, is my understanding over Debye's model wrong?)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Another good book! The $\omega^2$ in (3.32) is a specification of it being 3D space, that each direction in 3D space has one phonon of that same energy, and no more. So, kind of yes and no on your question.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent But why only one phonon for each direction each energy surface? (by the way, thanks for answering so many of my questions)

Comment: That is an assumption. It is not that bad, since in reality we have one longitudinal acoustic phonon and two transverse acoustic phonon (and Einstein's model can cover the optical phonons). That we can get good agreement with such crude models is already a great win.

Comment: Oh. I always thought that it is a physical fact. Does it simply reflect Debye's belief that different phonon's oscillation modes are somewhat related to each other?

Comment: No, they are simply looking for the cheapest mathematics to try to get some acceptable approximation. When you really need to get things correct very precisely, you go for better approximations. Say, you do Debye with different slopes for transverse v.s. longitudinal, or even better, do the entire phonon spectrum numerically.